# OpenPop Body c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, openpop

I am trying to read a body from e-mail, but on my datagridview I have only two messages and there is an information: "object reference not set to an instance of an object"

```
private DataTable dt;
private Pop3Client client = new Pop3Client();

private void button11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dt = new DataTable("Inbox");
    dt.Columns.Add("Subject");
    dt.Columns.Add("Sender");
    dt.Columns.Add("Body");
    dt.Columns.Add("Time");
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

     try
     {               
        client.Connect("pop-mail.outlook.com", 995, true);
        client.Authenticate(textBox6.Text, textBox5.Text);
        var count = client.GetMessageCount();
        int messageCount = client.GetMessageCount();
        for (int i = count; i >= 1; i -= 1)
        {
            OpenPop.Mime.Message message = client.GetMessage(i);                   
            OpenPop.Mime.MessagePart messagePart = message.MessagePart.MessageParts[1];

            string test = messagePart.BodyEncoding.GetString(messagePart.Body);

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { message.Headers.Subject, message.Headers.Sender, test, message.Headers.DateSent });
        }               
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how i can solve it to view all messages without  "object reference not set to an instance of an object" ?

Comment: on which line you get this error? It happens if you access an reference which consists null value. For example message = null; message.MessagePart would fire System.NullReferenceException.

Comment: i have problem with this lane " OpenPop.Mime.MessagePart messagePart = message.MessagePart.MessageParts[1];"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure, you message object is not null by check for null

```
OpenPop.Mime.Message message = client.GetMessage(i);
//Check you message is not null
if(message != null){
    OpenPop.Mime.MessagePart messagePart = message.MessagePart.MessageParts[1];

    string test = messagePart.BodyEncoding.GetString(messagePart.Body);

    dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { message.Headers.Subject, message.Headers.Sender, test, message.Headers.DateSent });
}
```